# API для кодирования Data Matrix Code

Tags: java, gradle, utf-8

Подскажите пожалуйста какое api можно использовать для кодировани DM кода. Пробовал изспользовать aspose.barcode и zxing, но у меня не получилось подтянуть зависимости через gradle т.к. все примеры были через maven и перелопатив гугл выяснил, что есть трудности с utf-8.
p.s. Я новичок, не судите строго.

Comment: подтянуть зависимости нужные получилось с помощью добавления следующего кода

dependencies {
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile "com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0"
    compile 'com.google.zxing:javase:3.4.0'
}

Comment: Но проблема с русскими буквами осталась.